# Reading USB camera button press event

Tags: python, events, button, camera, usb

This is simple USB camera with a snapshot button.

When the device is plugged into a USB port, I get this information from "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" on the host running Armbian Ubuntu 16.04.3:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=eb1a Product=2580 Version=0415
N: Name="UVC Camera (eb1a:2580)"
P: Phys=usb-sunxi-ehci-1/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/sunxi-ehci.2/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

That lead me to try the input device /dev/input/event2 -- but all my effort using python-usb and python-evdev (with sample code found here on StackOverflow) have so far failed to receive any input event when the button is pressed.

Your insights are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try to follow any step on http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

> Listing accessible event devices

```
   import evdev

   devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
   for device in devices:
   print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys)
```

> Listing device capabilities

```
import evdev

device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')
print(device)
```

> . 
>   .
>   .

to have all information like paths, which button is associated with which event ... from python